# How do I find what kernel structure something points to?

Tags: linux, kernel, kmem

I'm trying to debug an issue with kernel, where some function overwrites a random part of memory. I got some kernel oops on trying to read some unavailable memory area (usually 0x0...00282), which wasn't very helpful in debugging. But now I run into something potentially helpful - corruption happened in the file cache, so ended up with a nice fragment like this:

```
000bfc0: f0ef cf17 1888 ffff 8202 0000 0000 0000  ................
000bfd0: a0af 11a4 0a88 ffff a0af 11a4 0a88 ffff  ................
000bfe0: a0af 11a4 0a88 ffff 0094 aab3 0b88 ffff  ................
000bff0: 8202 0000 0000 0000 214e 1281 ffff ffff  ........!N......
```

So I've got my typical signature included two times (0x0282... in reverse order) and some data that looks like it could contain valid pointers. Is there any good way to try to identify the types of structures it points at? Or maybe structure (allocation) sizes at least? Are there any other useful information I could pull out of this?

I'm hoping that this fragment could help me figure out which module/function writes to the random address.

Comment: In addition to your analysis, perhaps, [Kmemcheck](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kmemcheck.txt) could be helpful in the future to debug similar issues?